# ReactViteTS on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, netlify

10:12:19 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
10:12:14 AM: Netlify Build
10:12:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: ❯ Version
10:12:14 AM:   @netlify/build 29.20.6
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: ❯ Flags
10:12:14 AM:   baseRelDir: true
10:12:14 AM:   buildId: 64e43c7ec1a82b1f9e1e75a0
10:12:14 AM:   deployId: 64e43c7ec1a82b1f9e1e75a2
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: ❯ Current directory
10:12:14 AM:   /opt/build/repo
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: ❯ Config file
10:12:14 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: ❯ Context
10:12:14 AM:   production
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: Build command from Netlify app
10:12:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:12:14 AM: ​
10:12:14 AM: $ npm run build
10:12:14 AM: > internapp@0.0.0 build
10:12:14 AM: > tsc && vite build
10:12:17 AM: src/DepartmentListComponent.tsx(1,8): error TS1259: Module '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag
10:12:17 AM: src/DepartmentListComponent.tsx(14,77): error TS7031: Binding element 'departments' implicitly has an 'any' type.
10:12:17 AM: src/DepartmentListComponent.tsx(50,24): error TS7006: Parameter 'department' implicitly has an 'any' type.
10:12:17 AM: src/main.tsx(1,8): error TS1259: Module '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag
10:12:17 AM: src/main.tsx(2,8): error TS1192: Module '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@types/react-dom/client' has no default export.
10:12:17 AM: src/main.tsx(3,17): error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './App.js' instead.
10:12:17 AM: ​
10:12:17 AM: build.command failed
10:12:17 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:12:17 AM: ​
10:12:17 AM:   Error message
10:12:17 AM:   Command failed with exit code 2: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
10:12:17 AM: ​
10:12:17 AM:   Error location
10:12:17 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
10:12:17 AM:   npm run build
10:12:17 AM: ​
10:12:17 AM:   Resolved config
10:12:17 AM:   build:
10:12:17 AM:     command: npm run build
10:12:17 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
10:12:17 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
10:12:17 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
10:12:19 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:12:19 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:12:19 AM: Finished processing build request in 43.496s

I'm trying to fix this error from last 3 days, please help me to fix it

Trying to fix this error from last e days but failed again and again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.